# Push existing repository to another repository

Tags: git, github

I have an existing .git project and have many commit message logs.I want to push this project to github.com, after doing that, I found that the commit logs also be pushed. How could I can push the existing project to github.com without old commit log?

Comment: Could you please clarify, what do you mean by *commit logs*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new repository:

```
git init new_repo
```

Copy every file in the repository, using, for instance :

```
cd old_repos
cp -r * ../new_repo
```

Commit and push everything

```
git add .
git commit -m "Initial commit"
git remote origin add github:myrepo
git push origin/master
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new orphan branch (branch without history) with `git checkout --orphan new-master && git add . && git commit -m "initial commit"`, then force-push this new branch without history to github with `git push -f origin new-master:master` or rename your local branches previously like `git branch -m master old-master && git branch -m new-master master` and just force-push.